# Why does this Google Calendar API request not return event data such as start time?

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api

I have a public Google Calendar; I would like to consume the data via Google's API and restylize it on the front-end in JavaScript. But when I make a request for the JSON, the data is... odd. There is no start or end times for the events, the event titles are HTML encoded, objects are nested under "$t" keys. I don't think this looks correct. What am I missing about using the calendar API?

Example: http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/dl9fj86o2ohe7o823s7jar920s@group.calendar.google.com/public/basic?orderby=starttime&sortorder=ascending&futureevents=true&alt=json

Comment: You are using calendar v2 which is deprecated on November 17, 2014. Try using calendar v3. Here is the link for the migration guide, https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making a call to API v2. I can tell by the URL which differs significantly from API v3. According to [Google Calendar API v2 Developer's Guide: Protocol](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/developers_guide_protocol)

*"This API is a subject to the Deprecation Policy and was shut down on November 17, 2014. Please use APIv3 instead."*

I assume you are viewing that data by GET request in your browser address bar. As soon as you start trying to use that same URL in an ajax request, I think you'll have headed down a path that ultimately results in you switching to API V3.